# Assign new value to variable used in while loop comparison after loop is entered

Tags: python

I was wondering if anything speaks against assigning a new value to a variable that is used in a comparison in a while loop after the while loop has been entered. A dummy example:

```
i = 0
target = 10
while i < target:
    print i
    if i == 9:
        target = 20
    i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, nothing stops you from doing that. Your example in and of itself is a proof.

Although, a better practice would be to use a `while True:` loop and `break` on a condition. Since your loop condition itself is prone to change, it's not really an invariant condition at all. Hence, I suggest you do:

```
i = 0
target = 10
while True:
    print i
    i = i + 1

    # If i hits 9 at any point, change target
    if i == 9:
        target = 20

    # If i ever hits the target, break
    if i >= target:
        break
```

Comment: I just wanted to make sure that it not only works, but also is good - or at least not bad - practice. In fact, your answer suggests that there might be a better solution... :-) Thank you.